# Want to revoke permission to access an app which has previously been given

Tags: permission

We previously gave permission for our daughter to access Instagram on her phone via family sharing and now no longer wish her to have access.  We have deleted the app and it has gone.  However, in the app store, Instagram displays the 'download cloud' and she can reinstall it without asking for permission again.  How can we stop this from appearing like this and push deleted apps to request permission again?

Comment: You could try a free MDM solution like [JAMF Now](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-now/). Although geared for business, it will give you the control over your daughter's iPhone you need. Best of all - its free.

Comment: Thanks - we will look into it!  I phoned Apple support and they were equally flummoxed.  I'm disappointed that despite using the Family protection, there is actually no way of protecting our family. In this instance, we intentionally granted access, but we may have accidentally done so and there is no way of revoking access.